# Timer within code

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

In my code I want to implement a timer which gives makes the death wait 2 seconds before it initializes.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Die();
}

void Die()
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

The death is instant and I want it to wait 2 seconds before it initializes.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean like "Thread.Sleep(..)") function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want it to happen after two seconds, you can try this -

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Invoke ("Die", 2.0f);
}

void Die()
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere initialize a timer with 2000 and define a handler, like this:

```
//...
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 2000; // 20 seconds
    tmr.Tick += timerHandler;
    tmr.Start(); // The countdown is launched!
//...
private void timerHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //handle death
}
//...
```

Comment: This isn't correct, sorry for pointing out but: Timer will be execute on its own thread so it will have 2 negative consequences: 1) Time accounted is not accurate if game is paused. 2) (worst) could led to exceptions if method callback modify any values that should be modified only from unity main thread.

Comment: I have not said not to handle pause. You can store the amount of elapsed time on pause and on resume you can create another timer with the remaining time. For the second problem, you can register somewhere the need to execute it. My answer solves the problem of timing and does not tackle with planning details.

Comment: Well, yes it's the standard c# way of doing that, sure. But the point is that inside unity engine, in typical use case scenarios this would led to errors or not intended behavior. Instead it provides some facilities for time management, because generally what you want (and what the OP asked for) is simulation time, not real time elapsed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Thread Dying = new Thread(()=>Die());
    Dying.Start(); //start a death in new thread so can do other stuff in main thread
}

void Die()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000); //wait for 2 seconds
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely wrong. You are blocking the main thread this way.

Comment: Please explain? I always do this to make something happen without interupting the rest of the application.

Comment: Sorry..my fault..actually you are not blocking because you are sleeping another thread. But it's still dangerous because you are potentially invoking a method (Die) from not the unity main thread. Btw, because I failed to read properly your answer, if you edit I may consider remove the downvote.